# what is going wrong with setting.xml and pom.xml while doing maven configuration

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I'm trying to explore maven as download tool as this helps in local caching as well connecting central/remote repository. I am able to download artifact from remote repository. But every time it downloads to target location but it doesn't look .m2 repository or updates there. I believe there is some setting which i am missing in setting.xml or pom.xml.

What goal i intend is download to check if already artifact is present in local repository can be .m2 or a predefined one and if not then only download from artifactory.

Maven Command Used :

```
mvn install pre-integration-test -f pom_download.xml -settings settings.xml -Dmayank=test.txt
```

output :

```
[INFO] --- wagon-maven-plugin:2.0.0:download-single (download-test-data) @ testdownload ---
[INFO] Downloading: https://artifactory.com/artifactory/test.txt to C:\downloads\test.txt
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  30.830 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-10-04T06:34:40-07:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Setting.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <proxies>
    <!-- proxy
     | Specification for one proxy, to be used in connecting to the network.
     | -->
    <proxy>
      <id>optional</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>https</protocol>
      <host></host>
      <port></port>
      <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>

    <proxy>
      <id>optional_1</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host></host>
      <port></port>
      <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
<localRepository>C:\repo_mayank</localRepository>
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>ubit-artifactory-or</id>
      <username>mayank</username>
      <password>xxxxx</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
    <id>artifactory</id>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>xxxx</id>
                <name>xxxx</name>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                    <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
                </snapshots>
                <url>https://artifactory.com/</url>
                <layout>default</layout>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
        <mirrors>
            <mirror>
                <id>our-server-repo</id>
                <name>C:\repo_mayank</name>
                <url>https://artifactory.com/</url>
                <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
            </mirror>
        </mirrors>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
   <activeProfile>artifactory</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Pom.xml

```
?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf8'?>
<project>
    <groupId>com.mayank</groupId>
    <artifactId>testdownload</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>wagon-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0</version>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>download-test-data</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>download-single</goal> 
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <task>
                                <echo> Hello World !!!</echo>
                            </task>

                            <serverId>artifactory</serverId>

                            <url>https://artifactory.com</url>
                            <fromFile>${mayank}</fromFile>
                            <toDir>C:\downloads</toDir>

                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
        <mayank> hello </mayank>
    </properties>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the maven wagon plugin doesn't use the maven cache at all. If you want to download artifacts linked to your project you can use the maven dependency plugin and use copy-dependencies goal. If you just want to copy some artifacts use the copy goal. More info: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/ Either way you have to specify what you want in your pom.

Comment: I replaced wagon like this : <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                           <version>3.1.1</version>  i am getting error like this Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.codehaus.mojo:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:3.1.1 in h

Comment: Then you are probably not connected to the internet or a firewall/proxy is blocking your access.

Comment: I fixed this with <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency> but now download is not happening. I am very new to maven, can you please help me here.

Comment: @Mighty_1989 Why do you use this old version instead of `3.1.1`? If you cannot download newer versions, you have a problem with your network/proxy/firewall/repository definition which you should fix first.